# Oracle job starts automatically

Tags: oracle, job-scheduling

I created job in Oracle. I set interval properly.  But the job started  automatically after I created it .

```
DECLARE
    X NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT ( 
         job => X 
          ,what => 'MISSING_REVENUE_EXPENSE_ICR;' 
          ,next_date => to_date('29/04/2015 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
          ,interval => '(trunc(sysdate)+1)+4/24' 
          ,no_parse => FALSE ); 
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
    COMMIT; 
END;
```

Why this happened? Tell me some fix for this issue.

Comment: Please provide your statement for job creation.

Comment: You must provide a "next date" for running the job - what date did you provide?

Comment: Please look at this code below:  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
  ( job       => X
   ,what      => 'MISSING_REVENUE_EXPENSE_ICR;'
   ,next_date => to_date('29/04/2015 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   ,interval  => '(trunc(sysdate)+1)+4/24'
   ,no_parse  => FALSE
  );
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
COMMIT;
END;

Comment: so for next_date i need to provide tomm. data .I provide todays date.I think this is issue right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
next_date => to_date('29/04/2015 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

That parameter has a misleading name, because it is the date for the initial run.  The [documentation shows what happens](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_job.htm#ARPLS66584) but doesn't entirely resolve the ambiguity.

Anyway, you have given today's date so it started today.